# How to duplicate all content (including forms) with PDFSharp?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

currently writing a small C# program with PDFSharp but I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out. The program is used to load in a pre-made PDF with a number of forms present, I want to read the original PDF in, duplicate it's contents into a new PDF and then fill out the forms in the new PDF. So far I have the following code:

```
inPDF = PdfReader.Open(sourceFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
outPDF = new PdfDocument();

for (int idx = 0; idx < inPDF.PageCount; ++idx)
{
   outPDF.AddPage(inPDF.Pages[idx]);
}
```

However the new PDF does not have any of the forms present in the original, how can I duplicate the contents (including forms) of the original PDF?

Thanks, RBrNx

Comment: Hello did you figured out ? I have exactly the same problem here. Thank you for sharing

Comment: Got that problem too. Can't figure out how to make that work. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I feel I am a bit late, but you almost got it back in those days!

You have 2 options, using `AddPage` or `InsertPage`. The main problem I encountered is that the Encoding was mandatory (I am not sure if it was only me) but here you have the code:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

sourceFile = "YourDirectory/YourOriginalDocument.pdf";
finalFile = "YourDirectory/YourFinalDocument.pdf";

var outPDF = new PdfDocument();
var inPDF = PdfReader.Open(sourceFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

for (int idx = 0; idx < inPDF.PageCount; ++idx)
{
    //outPDF.InsertPage(idx, inPDF.Pages[idx]); // if you prefer....
    outPDF.AddPage(inPDF.Pages[idx]);
}

// Save
outPDF.Save(finalFile);
```

Notice that you forgot to save the pdf (using method `Save`), but as I told you before, you were really close!

Answer (score 0):

Came across this recently as I had the same issue. It seems like form fields are considered PDF annotations, so just set the second parameter:

`outPDF.AddPage(inPDF.Pages[idx], AnnotationCopyingType.DeepCopy)`

I'm not sure if `DeepCopy` is necessary versus `ShallowCopy`, but it probably won't hurt.